# CKEditor 3.2.1 flash to link a video on my webpage

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 3.2.1.  want to link a video on my webpage. I copy youtube html url and paste in flash url field. But it does not work. What could be wrong? I am not a developer, just a simple user. Can you please help me in layman terms?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question fully, nor have I used CKEditor in the past, but it sounds like you're trying to embed a youtube video as a flash object? Try going to embed on youtube and using the html  code in CKEditor instead.

Update: alternatively, CKEditor has its own addon for embedding flash videos [here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube).